# Eclipse formats String inaccurately in JSP-File

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, string-formatting

Whenever I am using the short cut *Alt + Control + F* in *Eclipse Mars* it messes up the String "../css/stylesheet.css" in my *jsp* file.

It only occurs when the String is written in **<% %>** tags.

I looked up the section of *Java -> Code Style -> Formatter* and *HTML Files -> Editor* but couldn't find a solution.

Input:

```
<style type="text/css">
<%@include file="../css/stylesheet.css" %>
</style>
```

Output:

```
<style type="text/css">
<%@
include

file
="../css/stylesheet
.css
"

%>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In title you say `JSP` file, but in first line you say `css-file`, I will show both sollutions, but **if you have mixed `HTML` and `CSS` in same file, the option you need to modify is `HTML files`**.

Steps:

- Menu: `Window` > `Preferences`
- Inside preferences: 
  `Web` > **`HTML Files`** > `Editor`
                 `Web` > **`CSS Files`** > `Editor`
- Change **`line width`** to your preferred size.
  [image]
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to get desired reformatting ;)

OUTPUT AFTER / BEFORE:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I changed it from 72 to 200 and then 500, it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! The problem only occurs in my code is only when it comes to the <% xxx %> tags.